# In jmeter.bat file what is use of NewSize and MaxNewSize?

Tags: java, jmeter

While running jmeter script i was getting heap space error, 
my problem is solved by increasing heap size up to 4 Gb (-Xmx4096m), 
but i don't know that what is use of the **NewSize** and **MaxNewSize** 
Is it something related to heap size?

**I've set heap size as below in jmeter.bat file**

**`set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m`**

**`set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m`**

`set SURVIVOR=-XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50%`

`set TENURING=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes New size is part of Heap Size.
Read this:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

If you don't master GC Tuning, I suggest you comment :

```
#set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m
```